# strwidth: How to get the correct width for umlauts and other accented/special characters?

Tags: r, special-characters, diacritics

Consider the following example:

```
txt <- c("abc", "äéß")
nchar(txt)
# [1] 3 3
strwidth(txt, units = "inches", family = "mono")
# [1] 0.4166667 0.8333333
plot(0, type = "n"); text(1, c(0, .3), txt, family = "mono", cex = 5)
```

I'd have expected `strwidth` to return `[1] 0.4166667 0.4166667` when using a nonproportional font. Can I get the expected output without replacing the non-ascii characters? Thanks for your help.

Session info: R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09), Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1, locale: LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252, LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252,    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252, LC_NUMERIC=C,           LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252

### Edit:

**As noted in the comments, the `strwidth` problem seems to be a [known RStudio issue](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200654376-Incorrect-estimation-of-expression-wide-in-RStudio-plotting-window).**

Comment: What does `windowsFonts` report as the font in use for mono on your system?

Comment: `windowsFonts()$mono` returns `"TT Courier New"`.

Comment: Strange. That is the same as mine, but I can not reproduce.

Comment: Strange no 2: It seems to work in rgui.exe (just found out with regards to your comment), but does not work in RStudio 0.99.435.

Comment: Ah, it looks like it is an issue with the RStudio graphics device, although the plot itself doesn't seem to be affected.

Comment: You are right: If I open another graphics device than RStudio's null device (like `windows()` or `png()`) before calling `strwidth`, the output seems to be correct in RStudio, too.